# Evaluation of an integral and verification of proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am working on a problem from an old exam on analysis. I have almost finished it, but the very last step proved to be an obstacle. For the sake of completeness, and for the verification of my method, I will include my current progress in this post. Pointing out any errors will be appreciated.

First, define $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $$f(x,t)=\frac{\cos(xt)}{\cosh(t)}.$$
Write $f_x(t):=f(x,t)$, where $f_x:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$. First I have to show that $f_x$ is improperly Riemann-integrable. This function is clearly locally Riemann-integrable due to continuity. Since $f_x$ is symmetric around the $y$-axis, its improper Riemann-integrability is equivalent with its improper Riemann-integrability over $[0,\infty)$. For $t\ge0$, notice that  $|e^t+e^{-t}|=e^t+e^{-t}>e^t$. Furthermore, for all $x\in\mathbb R$, notice that

$$|f_x(t)|\le\frac{2}{e^t+e^{-t}},$$ since $|\cos(xt)|\le1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
Therefore $$|f_x(t)|\le\frac{2}{e^t+e^{-t}}<2e^{-t}.$$ Since $e^{-t}$ is improperly Riemann-integrable over $[0,\infty)$, which is a well-known fact, $f_x$ is also improperly Riemann-integrable over $[0,\infty)$ by the majorant characteristic for integrablitily. Thus it is Riemann-integrable by an earlier remark.

Next, I have to show that $$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,t)dt$$ is continuous. This is easy, since defining $g(t)=2e^{-|t|}$ and a little insight yields that $|f(x,t)|\le g(t)$ for all $(x,t)\in\mathbb R^2$ and that $g$ is improperly Riemann-integrable, which, along with continuity of $f$, implies the continuity of $F$.

Finally, I have to show that $F$ is also differentiable and I have to compute it's derivative. Again, the first part is relatively easy. Since $|t|g(t)$ is symmetric around the $y$-axis, its integral over $[0,\infty)$ coincides with the integral over $(-\infty,0]$. Moreover, if one of these exists, then $|t|g(t)$ is improperly Riemann-integrable. Over $[0,\infty)$ it's just the integral $$\int^\infty_02te^{-t},$$ which is known to converge. So $|t|g(t)$ is improperly Riemann-integrable. Now compute

$$D_1f(x,t)=-t\frac{\sin(xt)}{\cosh(t)},$$

which is clearly continuous. Since also $|D_1f(x,t)|\le |t|g(t)$ for all $(x,t)\in\mathbb R^2$, $F$ is differentiable, even continuously differentiable. Furthermore, $$F'(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty D_1f(x,t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,t)dt.$$ This is where I get stuck. Having computed the integral using Mathematica, I get a quite elegant form for $F(x)$, so my guess would be to compute this integral and then differentiate the computed function. I just can't see a method on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

A user in the comments pointed out that I had made a mistake. I have since then edited the original post accordingly, removing anything related to my previous, faulty insights.

EDIT 2:

From the discussion in the comments I am now pretty sure of the correctness of my method. Still, the integral remains unsolved (by hand). I also made some small changes to the text which incorporate my new insights.

Comment: In your formula for $D_1f(x,t)$, there's a factor of $t$ missing. Is that a typo or a mistake?

Comment: A mistake, thanks for pointing it out! I'm still not really sure how to proceed knowing this, however. Will (try to) edit my post to correct this error.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have edited my post to correct for your remark. Unfortunately, I did not gain any new insight on how to solve the last part of the problem. Could you (or anybody else reading this) please check my solution again (from the point of the error) and possibly help me understand how to compute the last integral?

Comment: I guess $$F'(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{t\sin (xt)}{\cosh t}\,dt$$ is the expected answer. You could ask Wolfram Alpha or any CAS if it knows a closed form. If it does, that probably gives a lead to proving it. If not, a closed form probably is not within reach.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, Wolfram Alpha (as well as Mathematica) do not provide a "nice" closed form, certainly in no way one a student is expected to come up with during an exam. This is very weird, as the original question explicitly states that I have to "compute" $F'$. As for the rest of my proof, is it fine this way?

Comment: Assuming the theorems about existence and continuity of the parameter dependent integrals that you used are legitimate to use, yes it's fine.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to take the integral over $\mathbb R$ so it was computing the integral in it's general form so to speak. Properly computed, Mathematica does provide a "nice" form. I will look into it. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the "nice" form?

Comment: It is the derivative of $\pi\cosh^{-1}(\frac{\pi x}{2})$, where this expression is $F(x)$, which I computed using Mathematica. However, computing $F'$ directly using Mathematica doesn't really give a very elegant form, but I guess that's just Mathematica being bad at automatically simplifying expressions or something like that.

Comment: Hmm, since $F(x) \to 0$ for $x\to \infty$, the $\cosh^{-1}$ there must mean $\frac{1}{\cosh}$ and not the inverse. But then the derivative would be simple, $$-\frac{\pi^2 \sinh \frac{\pi x}{2}}{2\cosh^2 \frac{\pi x}{2}}.$$ That shouldn't be expressed in a terrible way even by a CAS.

Comment: For the closed form, you could use the symmetry to write $F$ as an integral over $[0,+\infty)$ and then expand $$\frac{1}{\cosh t} = \frac{2}{e^t}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{-2t}} = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{-(2k+1)t}.$$ Interchange summation and integration (justification? Dominated convergence theorem for the Lebesgue integral, for Riemann you may need to fiddle a bit).

Comment: Yes you are right, in other words it is the function $\text{sech}$. I think the main difference here is that Mathematica does not "realise" that it can shift the differentiation out of the integral and just tries to "brute force" an answer from functions known to it, which results in a messy form (which even has an $i=\sqrt{-1}$ here and there).